# Using Invoke command on multiple computers. Need to export some results to location where invoke-command is running and name each file unique name

Tags: powershell

I am running invoke-command on lots of servers to gather info in parallel. I am then exporting the data locally on the server where the invoke-command is run. Problem i am having is exporting each job as its own unique $server.txt file when i am running invoke-command in parallel.

Contents of servers.txt file
Server1
Server2
Server3

Here is my current code..

```
icm -ComputerName (Get-Content c:\temp\servers.txt) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ThrottleLimit 15 -ScriptBlock{
$A=get some local server info
$B=get some local server info
$C=get some local server info

echo $A,$B,$C} | out-file c:\temp\$server.txt
```

Problem i have is that i want to export the results as a filename that is the server name the script is running on, and i cannot get the $server variable when using invoke-command to run these jobs in parallel.
i dont want to use a foreach loop because thats not in parallel.

i want the output for each serve to be in unique files like this.
C:\temp\server1.txt
C:\temp\server2.txt
C:\temp\server3.txt

EDIT:
I guess my other question or workaround would be is there any way to use a variable from inside the invoke-command loop outside?
I am gathering the machine name inside the invoke-command, but need to use it to set the filename of the export file.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
invoke-command -ComputerName (Get-Content c:\temp\servers.txt) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ThrottleLimit 15 -ScriptBlock{
    $data = @(
        get some local server info
        get some local server info
        get some local server info
    )
    $server = $env:computername
    $data | set-content c:\temp\$server.txt
}
```

should do the trick - but you could also receive the data directly:

```
$result = invoke-command -ComputerName (Get-Content c:\temp\servers.txt) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ThrottleLimit 15 -ScriptBlock{
    $data = @(
        get some local server info
        get some local server info
        get some local server info
    )
    return $data
}

$result | export-csv C:\data.csv -delimiter ";" -noclobber -notypeinformation
```

Comment: But i want the server name of each server in the c:\temp\servers.txt file, not the server name of where the invoke-command was run from.

Comment: the scriptblock runs on the remote computer... $server will contain the name of the remote computer... if you want the name in the text and not in the file name add $env:computername to the array $data

Comment: sorry, maybe i wasnt clear enough.. i want to export the $server.txt file on the machine where the invoke-command was initiated on. your edit exports the data on the local machine, not where the invoke-command was run,

Comment: take a look at the 2nd sample, there you receive all the data from the remote machine in the variable $result, I'll add the export....

Comment: your exporting the file C:\data.csv . i want to export with unique the filename of each server in the list.. c:\server1.csv, server2.csv, server3.csv... etc

Comment: why? you get the result of all machines, foreach element in this array you have the attribute PSComputerName, telling you from where the data is from... we can loop through the array and output foreach a file, but makes this sense?!

Comment: because when the invoke-command is run in parallel on hundreds of machines and writing back to the same file, there are file locks if 2 remote machines are both writing back to the same file at the same exact time, thats why i need it to write\export to unique file names.

Comment: there is no lock. you are receiving the data and write all data from all machines one time to the disk... just try my sample...

Comment: I cant use your sample for my purpose. i am querying hundreds of servers and writing a large about of variables back to a csv file in a particular order and also manipulating variables. i just need to know how to save the export to the machine running the invoke-command with the filename of each server in the list... thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: $result contains all data, each element stores the information received from 1 server, so if you want 1 file per server just do:
```$result | %{$_ | export-csv -path "C:\$($_.pscomputername.csv)"}``` as the received data itself is an array of objects its probably better to use json instead of csv

Comment: sorry typo: $result | %{$_ | export-csv -path "C:\$($_.pscomputername).csv"}

Comment: ok this works for outputting the server in the file name. thanks! but its not populating the file with all the local server info i am gathering like $env:computername;$env:username

Comment: without knowing what "get some local server info" should be its hard to say... in general if you want a csv we have to flattern the array, otherwise json would be a good choice: ``` $result | %{$_ | convertto-json -depth 4 | set-content -path  "C:\$($_.pscomputername.csv)"}```

Comment: thanks for your help. i appreciate it. But i need a solution based on my original code above, and this will not work with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would return an object instead, then you get the pscomputername property added on.

```
icm localhost,localhost,localhost {  # elevated prompt for this example
  $A,$B,$C=1,2,3
  [pscustomobject]@{A=$A;B=$B;C=$C}
} | ft


A B C PSComputerName RunspaceId
- - - -------------- ----------
1 2 3 localhost      40636f4b-0b65-494f-9912-82464e34c0f2
1 2 3 localhost      857d514c-8080-40ce-8848-d9b62088d75d
1 2 3 localhost      6ee0fd30-fb3a-4ad7-abba-bb2da0fbbece
```

Comment: you always get the PSComputername Info by running invoke-command, independently what datatype is returned

Comment: @toni That's true, although you would have to pipe it to `select-object *` to see it, if you were just returning a string.